# Custom UITableViewCell that has a style looking very much like UITableViewCellStyleValue2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'd like to create a UITableViewCell with two "TextLabels" in blue text on the left, and two "DetailTextLabels" in black on the right, as similar in style to UITableViewCellStyleValue2 as possible.

Up to now, I've set the TextLabel and DetailTextLabel text to be something really long (so that it'll take up the entirety of the width assigned to the blue labels), set the font to UIColor.Clear, and then taken their measurements each time they're rendered. That's horrible for lots of reasons, but it works in a fashion.

I'd like to accomplish this with a custom UIView and a custom Draw method. This is a prettier solution but now i'm missing a vital piece of information: the width of the area used to display a TextLabel. I could hard code it, which seems the accepted way to do things on iOS (even if it makes me feel dirty), but then I have to hard code it for iPad and iPhone both in Horizontal and Vertical orientations. And then it'd probably break as soon as my UITableView is plain instead of grouped, or somesuch.

Where can I get the standard, current width of this stupid label area?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried cell.frame.size.width?

Comment: @AlanZeino that would give me the width of the cell, not the width of the area assigned to the blue labels.

Comment: I think you may be approaching this backwards - what you want is the standard insets from the left and right edges of the cell, hardcode these and set your labels to auto size (flexible width) and this will cover you for portrait, landscape, iPad, etc. I'm not sure why you want to use a custom view and draw manually instead of adding labels as subviews?

Comment: @2ndMessage: Yes, but you can just define the proportion, in which the cell's area will be used for the blue and the black labels (like 2/3 of the cell's width is for blue; 1/3 - for the green labels). In any case the calculation of the widths is up to you.

Comment: The cell has to fit with every other normal UITableViewCell (left TextLabel font, width etc) and look like it came from apple themselves. Agreed, I could set it to 1/3 width of the cell, or 10 pixels from the left of the rounded corner on the right or whatever, but the text wouldn't line up perfectly with the normal, bold blue style labels that are shown in a standard UITableViewCellStyleValue2 styled cell. I need to define it to exactly the same width that the apple gods do. If I don't, it'll look cheap and out of place. There has to be some const or rectangle property I can prod, surely?

Comment: I was implementing my own class (let's say 'analyser') for a similar purpose (using NSString's sizeWithFont: function). I'll vote up your solution, if you find something ready-made.

Answer (score 1):

Each `UITableViewCell` has a `textLabel` and a `detailTextLabel`.  On `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`, the `textLabel` is on the left side and the `detailTextLabel` is on the right side.  Thus, you can access the left label's area like this:

```
cell.textLabel.frame
```

and you can access the right label's area like so:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.frame
```

Comment: that's right, but they have differing widths, based upon their content. I was hoping that there'd be a constant, or a property you could query, without having to nark around setting up fake content in the provided text labels, hiding them etc etc. I've already got this method down to pat, but I assume there is a cleaner way of querying simple properties of simple controls.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about making the cell in Interface Builder and using a static UINib to load it?  That seems fast enough for me, but I have not tested on anything slower then a 3GS.

If it is fast enough for your app I strongly recommend it, you will be able to make small (and large!) tweaks in the future with far less effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass a `UIView`, and inside your `drawRect` do the following.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSString *label = @"Label 1";
    CGSize size = [label sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f] 
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 100.0f) 
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];

    [label drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]];

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```